# Swift: Array find by identity

Tags: swift

The find function in swift only supports finding items equality (==). I want to find an item by identity (===). E.g. given this setup:

```
class A {}

let first = A()
let last = A()
let absent = A()
let array = [first, last]
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
find(array, first) // -> 0
find(array, last) // -> 1
find(array, absent) // -> nil
```

Does anyone the correct way to do this in swift?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a built-in library function, but this should work:

```
func findIdenticalObject<T : AnyObject>(array: [T], value: T) -> Int? {
    for (index, elem) in enumerate(array) {
        if elem === value {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The identical operator `===` is defined only for instances of *classes*, therefore
the generic function is defined only for `<T : AnyObject>`.

Comment: or you can just declare it `func findIdenticalObject(array: [AnyObject], value: AnyObject) -> Int?`, without generics